# How to Apply Style to Iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I like to have uniformity in my application style for my mobile.How to apply the styles to my control in the Iphone app ..Something similar to android resource files.. Even i hope thats one of the good pattern to follow in the application develovpment

Answer (score 0):

1. Buttons can be styled by using
   creating a custom button.
2. Custom views can be created using Interface builder or via code inheriting the UIview. A sample tutorial can be found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view)
3. You can create custom uitableview and uitableview cells too.

Resource files in android application is what Interface builder provides you in Xcode to create xib (nibs) for your ui layout.